# Flex - Source Size vs. Compile Size

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, flash-builder4.5

Could you explain why a Flash Builder source folder - no larger than 2 MB - compiles into a SWF exceeding 15 MB with debugging turned off (exported release build)?

There is only 1 embedded image at about 93k - no other images. The application is not that complicated, basically calls are made to a MySQL db to display information, as well as store information. I have used drop shadows and borders, but all standard to Flash Builder. Some custom classes and one custom skin.

Thank you...

Here is listing of the files:
    .DS_Store
    mx_4.5.1.21328.swz
    Main.html
    playerProductInstall.swf
    **Main.swf > 15 MB**
    rpc_4.5.1.21328.swz
    amf_config.ini
    services
    assets
    skins
    charts_4.5.1.21328.swz
    spark_4.5.1.21328.swz
    framework_4.5.1.21328.swz
    sparkskins_4.5.1.21328.swz
    gateway.php
    swfobject.js
    history
    textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, well...thought I'd revisit this since I found the problem - a font in a css file with embed set to 'true'. This font wasn't even being used, so I removed it and the css file completely (not in use either). They probably got inserted way early in the project. Code now hovering around 1 MB and less than that for the export build. Hope this helps someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty large to me.

When you say "Debugging Turned Off" what does that mean?  Did you export a release build?  Or did you just press the "play" button to run your code instead of the "Debug" button?

Do you have the Flex Framework linkage type set to RSL (AKA External) or Merge into Code?

Are you using an external libraries (SWC)?  A framework, such as RobotLegs or Swiz, could add to the size of the SWF; but will probably not be located in the source folder.

Comment: Hello: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did export the release build, cleaned the project a few times (which brought it to 14.9 MB), and made sure RSL was set. I'm not using a framework either. I've added the directory listing in case I'm not seeing something. Perhaps it is like Charmant says below: that it is all the dependent classes that FB adds causing the bloat.

Comment: Something seems amiss; without reviewing your project and/or code I'm unsure what.  I just checked the AIR project I'm working on; and my 2.5MB of code is compiling to a 1.8MB apk file.  The debug build is about 7MB, though.

Comment: Found it. See above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a collection of ActionScript classes and components, so when you build an app based on Flex, some of these classes get embedded into your application.

Something as simple as a `<s:Button` means that the byte code of `spark.components.Button` has to be included into your application along with your custom code, it's not part of the runtime.

Comment: not sure if FlashBuilder has an equivalent functionality, but in FlashDevelop, you can click on the [+] beside the swf file in the project window to see what classes are including in it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I do have RSL set, but I do think that Charmant is right in part. I'll follow back if I find something out - otherwise I guess it is what it is.

Comment: Hmm, Flextras is the expert, he certainly knows a lot more than me on the matter.